# Is it possible to liquidify plasma?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, pressure, plasma-physics, liquid-state

Plasma, of course, is quite energetic, but would it be possible to liquidify it (or maybe even solidify?) at sufficiently high pressures or by some other method, yet still retaining its charge. If yes, how big pressure would be required? Would surface tension work on a liquid plasma surface?

Comment: This seems similar to asking if you could have a liquid gas or a solid gas.  I'm not sure if it really makes sense.

Comment: Mobile charged particles in solid conductors exhibit collective behavior similar to gaseous plasmas therefore such systems are called solid-state plasmas, see, e.g., https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0508-3443/15/4/303/pdf

Comment: Magnetohydrodynamics is precisely this.  Namely, in certain limits a plasma can behave like a magnetized fluid.  It's not like water, obviously, but it can have fluid-like properties on certain scales.

Comment: Ok, thanks - i'll try looking more into MHD

Comment: @Krumuvecis Note that the MHD model does not necessarily describe a "liquid" - usually it describes a gas-like fluid. The rest depends on the equation of state. For what you are interested in the extremely dense (1000 g/cm$^3$) plasmas in ICF experiments would probably be relevant.

Comment: Maxim is correct though I will note that many MHD simulations have viscosities that make them as thick (or more) as honey ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, a plasma is defined by having long range electromagnetic interactions dominate over the short range intermolecular forces between particles. Taking this definition, I would say that you could not have a liquid-like or solid-like plasma as the liquid-like or solid-like properties would be a result of strong intermolecular forces.